# How to check In C# JArray have specific key pair

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I am working on JArray in .NET CORE and I am getting random structure of this one specific key, hence getting different error. I need to know if JArray has specific child Array and if Child JArray have specific key pair (NOT VALUE) i.e. value{ "Id":""}  one of error is following;

```
 Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "id". Int32 array index expected.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.get_Item(Object key) at
```

the standard structure I am expecting is as following;

```
{[value, [
{
  "id": "7ef82869-e235-69a2-f81e-3a9664e89bc4",
  "value": ""
 }
]]}
```

sometime I get as, meaning throw null error where I am trying to map Id.

```
 {[value, [
  {
   "value": ""
  }
 ]]}
```

and some Time I don't get this property at all

I am trying following check to cover all scenario but Its not really working.

### code

```
 if (answerItems.value != null && answerItems.value.HasValues && answerItems.value["id"]!=null)
                {
```

Comment: The "standard structure" you've shown is not valid JSON, so it's difficult for us to give you a specific answer. But it looks like you're trying to access `"id"` as a property on the array itself, rather than the property of a specific item inside. You could use LINQ to query the objects in the array, or you could use the SelectToken method to get an item that matches criteria you define in a string (e.g. `answerItems.value.SelectToken("[?(@.id == '')]")`).

Answer (score 4):

I received some constructive criticism on the brevity of my answer so I figured I would elaborate to help you through your issue.

First, let's take a look at your JSON. In short, it isn't valid. In fact, it isn't even close to valid JSON. I can only assume you meant something like this:

```
{
   "values" : [{ "id" : "7ef82869-e235-69a2-f81e-3a9664e89bc4", "value": "" }]
}
```

I would suggest that anytime you are trying to parse data like this and you run into issues you start trouble shooting by validating the data itself. I like to use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) for this.

Next, it is difficult from your example code to tell exactly what you are trying to do. I can only guess that you are attempting to use the `dynamic` object method of parsing and working with the data. A downside to this method is it is difficult to validate your data before you work with it.

Instead, I would use the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse` method. This gives you some tools for working with and validating the information. Below I have included a very simple example of how this would be done.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{ \"values\": [{ \"id\": \"7ef82869-e235-69a2-f81e-3a9664e89bc4\",   \"value\": \"\" }] }";
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

        // Check to see if we got our value array
        if (obj.ContainsKey("values")) {
            JArray values = (JArray)obj["values"];

            // Do we have any values in our array?
            if (values.Count > 0) {
                JObject firstItem = (JObject)values[0];

                // We check to see if we have an ID parameter
                if (firstItem.ContainsKey("id")) {
                    Console.WriteLine(firstItem["id"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in my original post, I would strongly recommend reviewing the [Newtonsoft.Json documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm).

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Good catch. I went ahead and elaborated for a better answer. Thanks for the critique!

Comment: ,many thanks shawn, I try what I learn from you. Json data structure done by someone and i cannot change structure so I have to play with what I have

Comment: If you can’t change the JSON then you won’t be able to use a JSON library to parse it. It isn’t JSON. You would be better off parsing it yourself with a custom parser.

Comment: This is much improved. Great job.